# Why is my war base not showing my upgrades?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have two base setups, one for my home base and one for wars. My war base does not show upgrades I have done on my defenses. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

After Preparation Day your Clan War Base is locked to the arrangement and highest completed upgrades

> ## How is my war base different from my village?
>
> Your war base is very similar to your village, with a few exceptions. Your war base does not generate resources. The clan castle in your war base must be filled separately from the clan castle in your village. War bases never need to have their traps rearmed, defenses reloaded, or heroes healed, as they are always ready for battle. **The war base can not be directly upgraded** or rearranged, but will instead mimic the arrangement and **highest completed upgrade levels of your village during the preparation day.** Buildings and traps will never be “under construction” in your war base.

Source: [Clash of Clans Wikia - War: The War Map (2nd question)](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ#How_is_my_war_base_different_from_my_village.3F) <sup>* emphasis mine</sup>

However it has came to my attention that the Wikia may be out of date as there was an update to the game that allowed you to have separate layouts however i so still believe the parts i emphasized still apply

as such any upgrades done after Preparation Day wont be applied to your Clan War Base until your next war. they will however still apply to your regular base

Comment: That FAQ might be outdated. There is a War Base tab in the Village Layout Editor which allows you arrange and set a base specifically for clan wars and which is distinct from your normal village. Everything else mentioned in that FAQ applies.

Comment: @Ellesedil i remember that update and thought it was strange the Wikia said it mimicked the regular base layout. i changed what parts i emphasized in the quote and made note that they should still apply

Answer (score 0):

In short, upgrades to your buildings and defenses(including walls) will only be apply after the war. Similar to placements. All edits done on your base(including newly constructed ones) will only be apply after the war.